# Most "Pythonic" way to have package install dependencies based on GPU presence/manufacturer?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I am currently developing a Machine Learning library that allows users to write CPU/GPU agnostic code to achieve certain tasks. In order to run the GPU enabled code, my package has certain dependencies which are only compatible with CUDA-enabled NVIDIA GPUs. Therefore, I would like my package to only install those dependencies when a user installs my package on a device with CUDA-enabled GPU. I researched how to do this, and at first it seemed as though my answer was going to be in [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/). Howevever, the `environment markers` described in this PEP do not include the presence of a GPU, let alone the manufacturer and/or drivers of that GPU.

Therefore, I am looking to see what the most "Pythonic" solution is to install certain dependencies based upon the presence of a CUDA-enabled NVIDIA GPU (if it is much easier to merely check for the presence of a NVIDIA GPU without checking for CUDA status I can do this as solution for the moment but I would definitely prefer to check for CUDA-enabled status).

I understand that `setup.py` is able to execute arbitrary Python code, so technically I can just solve this problem with code inside there that does this for me, but it is my understanding that the Python community is moving away from reliance on `setup.py` due to the inherent risks associated with the execution of arbitrary code during package setup, therefore I would like to be compliant with the community's preferences and have my solution use `pyproject.toml` if possible although I would also be happy to use `setup.cfg` if that is considered more appropriate (to be honest I do not feel like I fully comprehensively understand the distinction between these two files and which are more appropriate for what purpose, although from [the mCoding video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhUpxWjOhME) I watched to setup my testing it seems as though `setup.cfg` is more for package metadata).

Even though what I am looking to do was not expressly detailed in [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/), it feels very much "in the same spirit" so I would be surprised if there was no canonical way to do this.

Comment: The most Pythonic way is to send a pull request to [`pip`/`setuptools`](https://pypa.io/) authors that adds GPU flag in addition to Python version, processor architecture and bitness.

Comment: It does seem like there are many discussions about adding something like that to Python (https://discuss.python.org/t/what-to-do-about-gpus-and-the-built-distributions-that-support-them/7125/3, https://discuss.python.org/t/idea-selector-packages/4463/2, https://discuss.python.org/t/archspec-a-library-for-labeling-optimized-binaries/3149) but I still need a solution for the time being

Comment: any news on this? did you manage to find a way to do it? I'm struggling with exactly the same issue.